# Apple Push Notification API Not Throwing Error With Bad Device Token

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, http2

I'm currently setting up an apple push notification server for my app and I have a question regarding apple's responses. It's my understanding that the *new* push notification api (`http2`) allows you to receive instant feedback for each message sent through the service, and for the most part that seems to be true. However, I'm running into the issue that when I go into my iPhone's settings and remove the app's ability to send notifications apple still returns a '200' http2 response code, not the error '410' like it should. What would be a reason why it would still give the '200' response?

Comment: hey bro, did you solved this issue? im facing the exact same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290613/apns-http2-api-not-returning-status-410-after-uninstalling-app