# HTTP2 based APNS request response is success despite uninstalling the app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, http2, apns-php

I was able to get the right info after a successful APNS request, whether the device token is invalid or not.

Lately, I realized that even though the user uninstalled the app, I get a "200 success" response from the APNS server.

Did something change or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It's depened on Apple side. 
See [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116543) for more details:

> APNs will eventually report that the push token is invalid after an
>   app has been uninstalled. The time between an uninstall and the
>   invalidation is dependent on various factors, and the details of when
>   this will happen is not documented.
>
> The guidance here is to send the puhes to devices until you receive an
>   error response from APNs. Sending pushes to non-existent apps does not
>   cause any harm.
>
> We have no recommendations for determining when users uninstall apps.
>   Our current implementation is indeed designed to avoid such detection
>   by developers, and as such, we have no services, API, or code samples
>   to have alerts sent when an app is uninstalled.

See also this answer for more ideas:
[apns http2 api not returning status 410 after uninstalling app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290613/apns-http2-api-not-returning-status-410-after-uninstalling-app)